# How to reload data in free jqgrid 4.15.4

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I have a question regarding free jqgrid. My jqgrid is loading fine with all data. I have given one dropdown and search button explicitly. when I am trying to search by selecting the dropdown and clicking on search button, New data is not loading into existing grid.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x3fger4z/.

On page load, I am using this url: '/MajorsView/GetAllData',  but after clicking on button I wanted to load from another url.

Below is my search button and actually I am getting data in success, but it is not reflecting on grid:

```
<input type="button" onclick="return myfunction();" id="btnFlagStatus" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />

function myfunction() {
 var gendarVal = $("#gendarFlagsEnum option:selected").text();
        var URL= "/MajorsView/GetFemaleData?searchKey=" + gendarVal;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: URL,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(gendarVal),
            datatype:"json",
            success: function (data) {
                //$("#grid").setGridParam({ url: URL })
                $("#grid").trigger('reloadGrid');

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        })
}
```

I have tried to taken references from these but no avail

- [How to filter the jqGrid data NOT using the built in search/filter box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819)
- [how to reload jqgrid in asp.net mvc when i change dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839721/how-to-reload-jqgrid-in-asp-net-mvc-when-i-change-dropdownlist/2842199#2842199)
- [jQuery button click refresh of jqGrid only firing once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155644/jquery-button-click-refresh-of-jqgrid-only-firing-once)

Comment: The demo https://jsfiddle.net/x3fger4z/, which you included seems to have no relation with your problem. Which `datatype` have your grid? The line `$("#grid").setGridParam({ url: URL })` is commended in your code. Why? Your current code loads the data from `URL` **directly** with respect of Ajax request, but if **you don't use the server response**. The `data` parameter of `success` callback will be not used. It's difficult to help you without any knowledge (knowing the options) how you use jqGrid.

Comment: Hey Oleg, the fiddle that i added in the question is what my grid looks like on my machine. My grid has datatype : json with loadonce: true. From the given function i am getting data in ajax success. But the data isn't loading into existing grid. With this line i thought the data will load into grid but it didnt worked. $("#grid").setGridParam({ url: URL })

Comment: To clarify question: I have two methods in controller one from which I'm getting all data on page load ('/MajorsView/GetAllData',) . 

 Another action method is what I passed into the above function which should show filtered records in the same grid. But grid is not refreshing with new ( filtered) records.

Comment: For example on page load I have 5 records, but when I do searching from explicit button click then this show only filtered records in grid. 
Again trying to keeping this clear that in my code I have two different methods one which brings all data and another which only bring filtered data.
I hope this clarify better. Btw thanks Oleg :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `datatype: "json"` with some `url`, then you can just change `url` to another value and to trigger `reloadGrid`. One don't need to make a manual Ajax request. If you use `loadonce: true` option additionally, then `datatype` of the grid will be changed to `"local"` to process sorting, paging and filtering *locally*. Every sorting, paging and filtering is nothing more as reloading the grid which has `datatype: "local"` with another parameters (like `page`, `sortname`, `postData.filters`). Thus to reload the data of the grid *from the server* one have to restore `datatype` to the initial value (`"json"` in your case). Thus you can use

```js
var p = $("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam"); // get reference to all parameters of jqGrid
p.url = "/MajorsView/GetFemaleData?searchKey=" + encodeURIComponent(gendarVal)
$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid", { fromServer: true });
```

Alternatively ole can reset `datatype` directly (with `p.datatype = "json";`), but the usage of `fromServer: true` could be helpful in other scenarios and it makes the code more readable in my opinion. See **UPDATED** part of [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398136/315935) for additional information.

Comment: Can you give more insight on first sentence (after first comma) :  **then you can just change url to another value and to trigger reloadGrid. One don't need to make a manual Ajax request.** do you mean change url dynamically? If yes then , any example answer link. As I was applying two jqgrid with different urls.

Comment: @Chandan: I mean that you should remove Ajax call from `myfunction` and just use the code from my answer instead. It sets `url` parameter and then use `reloadGrid` with `{ fromServer: true }` parameter. The grid should be reloaded from new `url`.

Comment: Hey @Oleg, I did the same but encodeURIComponent(gendarVal) is passing as null on controller action method.

Comment: @Chandan: Do you initialized `gendarVal` before (`gendarVal = $("#gendarFlagsEnum option:selected").text()`)? The method `encodeURIComponent` is standard JavaScript method which makes safe the usage of special characters in URL. If `gendarVal` has no special characters the one can use `"/MajorsView/GetFemaleData?searchKey=" + gendarVal`, but `encodeURIComponent(gendarVal)` is safer as `gendarVal`.

Comment: I got that Oleg, thanks. Instead of passing searchKey to action controller method as a param, I was passing genderVal. which having no scope after passing value to searchKey in url.  I have marked this answer as accepted but it will not reflect for others. so may be moderator can mark this answer as accepted. Many thank Oleg, You are awesome!

Comment: Yes Oleg, I know that ,but my rep count is less than 15 so it will not visible to others.

Comment: @Chandan: I see that your reputation now is 16. Probably you need just reload the page in the web browser. You *should* be able to accept and to vote.